# System thread (ntoskrnl.exe!ExTryQueueWorkItem) causing high cpu usage

Tags: windows-10, performance

The system process has been randomly using about 15% of my CPU for about an hour then goes back down again. I used the Process Explorer threads tab to see that ntoskrnl.exe!ExTryQueueWorkItem+0x5a20 has been using the most CPU in the system process. Can anyone tell me what that means?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating my NVIDIA drivers and Windows.